# ADFS 2016 + OAuth 2.0: Grant native application to access to profile's scope

Tags: oauth, adfs

I am able to get the token to my https://myserver/adfs/oauth2/token with the scope = openid, but not with profile, I got:

```
{
  "error": "unauthorized_client",
  "error_description": "MSIS9605: The client is not allowed to access the requested resource."
}
```

I don't found any documentation that explains how to grant this permission.

Comment: I solved my question using a different approach, I was using a Native Application, I found that if I use a **Web browser accessing a web application** instead I'm able to customize the Claims, in which I can include additional information for the user such as name, email, groups, etc, without need to call the /adfs/userinfo endpoint

Comment: I’d love to know how you did that Ignacio! We are struggling to get custom claims returned in the access token. Could you explain please?